# Looping through multi-dimensional arrays in Java

Tags: java

I'm having a bit of trouble creating a Text RPG in Java:

```
private int[][][] tiles = {


            /* 0,0     0,1     0,2     0,3     0,4     0,5     0,6  */
            { {},     {},     {},     {},     {},     {},    {} },
            /* 1,0     1,1     1,2     1,3     1,4     1,5     1,6  */
            { {},     {},     {},     {},     {},     {},    {} },
            /* 2,0     2,1     2,2     2,3     2,4     2,5     2,6  */
            { {},     {},     {},     {},     {},     {},    {} },
            /* 3,0     3,1     3,2     3,3     3,4     3,5     3,6  */
            { {},     {},     {},     {},     {},     {},    {} },
            /* 4,0     4,1     4,2     4,3     4,4     4,5     4,6  */
            { {},     {},     {},     {},     {},     {},    {} },
            /* 5,0     5,1     5,2     5,3     5,4     5,5     5,6  */
            { {},     {},     {},     {},     {},     {},    {} },
            /* 6,0     6,1     6,2     6,3     6,4     6,5     6,6  */
            { {},     {},     {},     {},     {},     {},    {} }

    };
```

I have an array of tiles for a 'Room' in my Java game, I'm trying to access each tile and set it to either a '1' or '0' and I'm having an 'Index 0 out of bounds for length 0' error using this function -

```
 // loops through multi-array and sets each tile to 1 or 0 if not already a door (2)
    public void create_grid() {
        boolean door_set = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
                if (tiles[0][i][j] != 2) { // Error on this line
                    tiles[0][i][j] = d1.tile_spawn(); // Returns 1 or 0 randomly
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: None of your inner-most arrays have any elements, so they are all of length 0.  What value do you expect `tiles[0][i][j]` to have for any given value of `j` and why?

Comment: You have initialized all the arrays as emtpy ones and arrays are not dynamically growing by simply adding items to them. That's exactly what the error message is telling you: You cannot put anything into an array that has 0 slots.

Comment: That problem is at your 3rd coord, all of them has 0 length. Which means you can't even access position 0. Why you don't simply initialize like `int[][][] tiles = int[6][6][99]` , 99 or whatever you want/need.

Comment: @David I basically wanted each j tile to contain a '1' or '0', am I doing the wrong thing to check the value of the tile?

Comment: don't use literals, use `tiles.length, tiles[i].length, tiles[i][j].length`... and so on

Comment: @KeirHewitt: If you want each tile to contain a value, put a value in the arrays.  Right now you're trying to "check the value" when there *is no* value there.  Look closely at the array structure you've created.  Where do you see any value to "check"?

Comment: @deHaar how can I initialize this so that each j tile contains an array of 1 int?

Comment: Read the answer given by @ernest_k, it actually tells you how to initialize the array like that in two different ways

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are initializing your array with initializer lists, only your 3rd level arrays are all empty (`{}`). If you want to keep using said initializer lists, you'd have to put a value in each of the innermost arrays, to make them of length 1. That would look like this -

```
private int[][][] tiles = {


            /* 0,0     0,1     0,2     0,3     0,4     0,5     0,6  */
            { {1},     {1},     {1},     {1},     {1},     {1},    {1} },
            /* 1,0     1,1     1,2     1,3     1,4     1,5     1,6  */
            { {1},     {1},     {1},     {1},     {1},     {1},    {} },
            /* 2,0     2,1     2,2     2,3     2,4     2,5     2,6  */
            { {1},     {1},     {1},     {1},     {1},     {1},    {1} },
            /* 3,0     3,1     3,2     3,3     3,4     3,5     3,6  */
            { {1},     {1},     {1},     {1},     {1},     {1},    {1} },
            /* 4,0     4,1     4,2     4,3     4,4     4,5     4,6  */
            { {1},     {1},     {1},     {1},     {1},     {1},    {1} },
            /* 5,0     5,1     5,2     5,3     5,4     5,5     5,6  */
            { {1},     {1},     {1},     {1},     {1},     {1},    {1} },
            /* 6,0     6,1     6,2     6,3     6,4     6,5     6,6  */
            { {1},     {1},     {1},     {1},     {1},     {1},    {1} }

    };
```

You could also initialize your array with the `new` keyword. That would look like this -

```
private int[][][] tiles = new int[7][7][1];
```

Please note, that since each of your innermost arrays have only one value, they are actually moot - you could just use a two-dimensional array. Your code would look like this then -

```
private int[][] tiles = new int[7][7];
```

with your grid function looking like this -

```
public void create_grid() {
        boolean door_set = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < tiles.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < tiles[0].length; j++) {
                if (tiles[i][j] != 2) { // Error on this line
                    tiles[i][j] = d1.tile_spawn(); // Returns 1 or 0 randomly
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The clear reason for the error you're getting is that your innermost arrays are initialized as empty. Accessing any index of an empty array would produce an exception.

You either initialize your array elements with a value...

```
private int[][][] tiles = {{ {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0} }, ...
```

Or, if you let it, Java will set the default value:

```
private int[][][] tiles = new int[7][7][1];
```

---

The important side note is that you probably don't need a 3D array. Because your "tile" values are just 1 or 0, you surely don't need to wrap them in singleton arrays. You can just use

```
private int[][] tiles = new int[7][7]; //all values default to 0.
```

Which makes your loop look like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
        if (tiles[i][j] != 2) { 
            tiles[i][j] = d1.tile_spawn(); 
        }
    }
}
```